# Understanding zsh blobing, alias, and tab completion

Tags: zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh, tab-completion

I am new to `zsh` and recently moved on from `csh`, due to obvious reasons.

Oddly enough, its taking me slightly longer than I expected to port a lot of aliases which I use extensively. Here's one of them.

In my csh i have a "cd test case" as follows

```
alias cdtc 'cd $TOP/\*/\*/tests/!*'

complete cdtc 'p#1#`/bin/ls -1 $TOP/*/*/tests | perl -lne '"'"'print if $_!~m/\// && $_!~m/^$/'"'"'`#'
```

1. I guess the complete command prints a neat little coloured list of options of all test cases in all tests folders in my hierarchy, when I press tab.
2. Partial matches are honoured. i.e. `$> cdtc type_a_ <tab>` would show directories beginning only with `type_a_`, but from all hierarchical locations
3. While I understand the alias, I don't completely understand that perl expression; but I do know it's mostly related to the list of directory names being pretty and not in a single column. Lack of complete grasp is because I did not compose the alias nor the completion command.

**My expectation in zsh**

I Expected that the complete command wouldn't be necessary and just the alias would do. I've come across a few online posts which discuss _path_files but I couldn't find anything like `_path_dirs`.

I would like some pointers.

Comment: corrected cdtc 'cd $TOP/\*/\*/tests/!*'

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your `~/.zshrc` file and you'll get pretty decent tab completion:

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -C
bindkey '^I' complete-word
```

No need to mess around with aliases or functions. If you want to customize how the completion works, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html

Or if you don't want to be bothered figuring out how all these settings interact with each other (which can get quite complex quickly), try my plugin [marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete). It auto-configures Zsh's completion system for a great out-of-the-box experience and gives you real-time completion as you type.